# URL.openStream() and HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent() downloading different files of Inputstream

Tags: java, http, httpclient, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

Using URL class in java.net package.

**Method 1**

```
        String sourceUrl = "https://thumbor.thedailymeal.com/P09kUdGYdBReFSJne1qjVDIphDM=//https://videodam-assets.thedailymeal.com/filestore/5/3/0/2_37ec80e4c368169/5302scr_43fcce37a98877f.jpg%3Fv=2020-03-16+21%3A06%3A42&version=0";
        java.net.URL url = new URL(sourceUrl);
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("/Users/test/rr.png"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Using Apache's HttpClient class.

**Method 2**

```
        String sourceUrl = "https://thumbor.thedailymeal.com/P09kUdGYdBReFSJne1qjVDIphDM=//https://videodam-assets.thedailymeal.com/filestore/5/3/0/2_37ec80e4c368169/5302scr_43fcce37a98877f.jpg%3Fv=2020-03-16+21%3A06%3A42&version=0";
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sourceUrl);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        InputStream inputStream = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
        Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("/Users/test/rr.png"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I have downloaded the rr.png file using both the methods. I found both the files are different even in sizes also and using method 2 download a blank image. I have read both the methods are same but I do not understand why method1 downloading correct file and method2 downloading wrong file. Please clarify this and also let me know if there is a fix in the method 2 through which I can download the correct file.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:apache] tag (twice), because this question is _not_ related to *Apache httpd*. Before editing this again, please read the tag's description, which is quite clear on its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First: cross-posting: https://coderanch.com/t/728266/java/URL-openStream-HttpResponse-getEntity-getContent

Second: I guess the issue is the url and how it's handled differently by javas internal class and apache lib - use a debugger and step through them to see what url really gets send out the tls stream.